# $location.path not refreshing page in the IE browser

Tags: angularjs

I am using `$location.path` to redirect to a specific url. This is working in other browsers perfectly, but, in Internet Explorer it does not work.

I have tried with:

```
request.success(function (html) {
    if(html['success'] == 1){
        $("#couponFrm")[0].reset();
    }        
    $("#spinner").hide();
    if(html['success']){
        launch("notify", html['msg']);
        $location.path("/coupons`enter code here`");                
    }
    else{
        launch("error", html['msg']);     
    }    
});
```